# dlib example, test builds fail

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dlib

Running ubuntu 12.04, I downloaded the source and compiled it as instructed (see https://github.com/davisking/dlib). Below is the error message displayed.

```
cmake --build . --config Release
[ 1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
In file included from /home/andreif/downlib/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/parallel_for_extension.h:9:0,
from /home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads.h:24,
from /home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/sockets_kernel_2.h:33,
from /home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/posix.h:4,
from /home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets.h:14,
from /home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/bsp.h:7,
from /home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/bsp.cpp:6:
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h: In function ‘std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes="" ...)="">::type> dlib::async(dlib::thread_pool&, Function&&, Args&& ...)’:
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:63:15: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘bind_t’
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:63:15: error: ‘bind_t’ has not been declared
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:63:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:63:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:63:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘decltype’
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:63:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘decltype’
/home/my_path/dlib-19.2/dlib/bsp/../sockets/../threads/async.h:64:37: error: ‘bind_t’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my c++ compiler: the default gcc 4.6 in ubuntu 12.04 has c++11 support, but it has to be enabled at the command line when calling it. I tried editing /.bashrc to automatically do this, but it didn't work. The solution for me was to install gcc/g++ 4.8 (and use update-alternatives to keep the old installation usable), as described here

http://mortenvp.com/installing-a-newer-gccg-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the problem is now solved.